# In matlab, speed up cross correlation

Tags: performance, matlab, cross-correlation

I have a long time series with some repeating and similar looking signals in it (not entirely periodical). The length of the time series is about 60000 samples. To identify the signals, I take out one of them, having a length of around 1000 samples and move it along my timeseries data sample by sample, and compute cross-correlation coefficient (in Matlab: corrcoef). If this value is above some threshold, then there is a match.
But this is excruciatingly slow (using 'for loop' to move the window). 
Is there a way to speed this up, or maybe there is already some mechanism in Matlab for this ?

Many thanks

Edited: added information, regarding using 'xcorr' instead:

If I use 'xcorr', or at least the way I have used it, I get the wrong picture. Looking at the data (first plot), there are two types of repeating signals. One marked by red rectangles, whereas the other and having much larger amplitudes (this is coherent noise) is marked by a black rectangle. I am interested in the first type. Second plot shows the signal I am looking for, blown up.
If I use 'xcorr', I get the third plot. As you see, 'xcorr' gives me the wrong signal (there is in fact high cross correlation between my signal and coherent noise). 
But using "'corrcoef' and moving the window, I get the last plot which is the correct one.
There maybe a problem of normalization when using 'xcorr', but I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Why not `xcorr`? Or `conv`? Those functions move the window automatically. However, the result is not normalized as with `corrcoef`. But you can correct for that

Comment: Did you try using `normxcorr2`? It's intended for 2D data, but I imagine it should work for times series too.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to speed things up.

1) make your template 1024 elements long. Suddenly, correlation can be done using FFT, which is significantly faster than DFT or element-by-element multiplication for every position.

2) Ask yourself what it is about your template shape that you really care about. Do you really need the very high frequencies, or are you really after lower frequencies? If you could re-sample your template and signal so it no longer contains any frequencies you don't care about, it will make the processing very significantly faster.  Steps to take would include

- determine the highest frequency you care about
- filter your data so higher frequencies are blocked
- resample the resulting data at a lower sampling frequency

Now combine that with a template whose size is a power of 2

You might find [this link](http://simon.rozman.si/computers/dsp/block-wise-cross-correlation) interesting reading.

Let us know if any of the above helps!

Comment: Thanks. Good points. Does Matlab use FFT for cross correlation? Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like a textbook example of cross-correlation. Therefore, there's no good reason using any solution other than `xcorr`. A few technical comments:

1. xcorr assumes that the mean was removed from the two cross-correlated signals. Furthermore, by default it does not scale the signals' standard deviations. Both of these issues can be solved by z-scoring your two signals: `c=xcorr(zscore(longSig,1),zscore(shortSig,1)); c=c/n;` where `n` is the length of the shorter signal should produce results equivalent with your sliding window method.
2. xcorr's output is ordered according to lags, which can obtained as in a second output argument (`[c,lags]=xcorr(..`). Always plot xcorr results by `plot(lags,c)`. I recommend trying a synthetic signal to verify that you understand how to interpret this chart.
3. xcorr's implementation already uses Discere Fourier Transform, so unless you have unusual conditions it will be a waste of time to code a frequency-domain cross-correlation again.

Finally, a comment about terminology: Correlating corresponding time points between two signals is plain correlation. That's what `corrcoef` does (it name stands for correlation coefficient, no 'cross-correlation' there). Cross-correlation is the result of shifting one of the signals and calculating the correlation coefficient for each lag.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Though I did not know about ZSCORE, I already have detrended and divided the data by its standard deviation. Both the signal of interest and the coherent noise are originated by moving sources. The resulting length of both are thus changing over time. The further the source the more stretched the signals become. I am aware of the "lag" output of the "xcorr". In this case, I don't think it would help resolving the problem though.